# call nodeHandle->advertiseService

Tags: ros, rosservice, roscpp, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i try to advertise my service, but i am not able to compile.

Here is my msg file:

```
string sourceRobot
float64 x
float64 y
```

My srv file:

```
map_merger/pointFromRobot inputPoint
---
map_merger/pointFromRobot outputPoint
```

And here are the cpp parts according to the Service:

in map_merger.h:

```
 map_merger::pointFromRobot transformPoint(map_merger::transformPoint::Request req);
```

in map_merger.cpp:

```
 map_merger::pointFromRobot transformPoint(map_merger::transformPoint::Request req)
 {
     map_merger::pointFromRobot returnValue;
    return returnValue;
}
```

in the Constructor the advertiseService is called (that does not work), here is the code:

```
 nodeHandle = new ros::NodeHandle("~");
    ros::ServiceServer service = nodeHandle->advertiseService("transformPoint",&MapMerger::transformPoint,this);
```

regard peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151476/call-nodehandle-%3Eadvertiseservice/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2014-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have compile errors, you should always post them along with your question.

It appears you are not using the correct signature for the callback function, as described in [Writing a Simple Service and Client (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(c%2B%2B)), it should have two arguments (one for the request, one for the response).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2014-04-11**:
i will post the error in future questions. I had to change the method to:

```
bool transformPoint(map_merger::transformPoint::Request &req,
                    map_merger::transformPoint::Response &res);
```